# Геокоординаты MapKit Android

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

Разрабатываю приложение для заказа такси на android (java) использую библиотеку MapKit, создал карту в активити, получаю текущее местоположение, но встал вопрос как сделать так что бы при перемещении карты я получать геокоординаты центра карты в области которую я вижу, в активити добавил картинку в центр карты наподобие крупных такси что бы перемещаешь карту а маркер остается на месте и маркер получает координаты там где его остановят, собственно как это реализовать не пойму.

Answer (score 1):

Решил данный вопрос

```
        final Session searchSession = searchManager.submit(
            new Point(mapView.getMap().getCameraPosition().getTarget().getLatitude(), mapView.getMap().getCameraPosition().getTarget().getLongitude()),
            18,
            new SearchOptions().setSearchTypes(SearchType.GEO.value),
            new Session.SearchListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSearchResponse(Response response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSearchError(Error error) {

                }
            });
```